# How pass int list from action to view, then from view to method in mvc 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax, viewbag, tempdata

In MVC4 application in `Create`(post) action I want to pass **int type list** to view if error occur. And then, from there to pass it to other method in same controller with ajax post. So, `TempData`, `ViewData` and `ViewBag` don't help me.

```
public ActionResult Create(CreateModel model)
       {
             if(hasCustomError)
             {
                  List<int> selectedItems = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 8 }; //for example.
                  ViewBag.VB = selectedItems;

                  //ViewData["VD"] = selectedItems;
                  //TempData["TD"] = selectedItems;

                   return View(model);
             }

             return RedirectToAction("Index");
       }
```

After `return View(model);`, list of `selectedItems` passed to `Create.cshtml` view. It has value here I checked. But from here I should pass that list to `GetTreeData` method via ajax post:

```
@{
   if (ViewBag.VB != null)
      {
          TempData["SelectedItems"] = ViewBag.VB as List<int>;
      }
}


    $("#myTree").jstree({
        json_data: {
            "ajax": {
                url: "@Url.Action("GetTreeData", "MyController")",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json charset=utf-8"
            }
        },
        checkbox: {
            real_checkboxes: true,
            checked_parent_open: true
        },
        plugins: ["themes", "json_data", "ui", "checkbox"]
    });
```

In the `MyController`, in `GetTreeData` method `TempData["SelectedItems"]` is `null` .

```
 public string GetTreeData()
        {
           List<int> selecteds = null;
           if (TempData["SelectedItems"] != null)
            {
                selecteds = TempData["SelectedItems"] as List<int>;
                TempData["SelectedItems"] = null;
            }
            ......................................
        }
```

I tried this for all (TempData, ViewData and ViewBag). nothing changed.

How can pass that list from action to view and then from that view to method?

Comment: I found solution. First I convert int list to string list as "1,2,8" and then, 

url: "@Url.Action("GetTreeData", "MyController",  new { param = stringList })",

Answer (score 1):

Create a viewmodel, in that viewmodel set your model that you are using now as a field, and add an extra field for that list

Comment: yes I have not other way I see. I'll not find any way, do such.